# Theme switcher not working , no cookie

Tags: jquery

I am using this method shown here http://leihu.com/thoughts/e/switching-styles-silently

Here is my head

```
<link href="default.css" title="common-styles" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" class="theme">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is my html and script for the stylesheet switcher. While its working to toggle back and fourth between the 2 sheets , on page refresh its not remembering the last stylesheet chosen.

```
<ul class="themes">
    <li><a href="#" rel="default.css">Default</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="alternative.css">Alternative</a></li>  
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.themes a').on('click',function(){
            $('.theme').attr('href',$(this).attr('rel'));
            $.cookie('theme-cookie',$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/', domain: '.mysite.com'});
            return false;
        });

});
</script>
```

I have changed mysite.com to my own site ofc , and i think i have done everything correctly but not setting a cookie for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set it when you load the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ==============
    // theme switcher
    // ==============

    // load css from cookie!
    $(".theme").attr("href", $.cookie('theme-cookie'));

    // listen for clicks on the a links within .themes
    $('.themes a').on('click',function(){
        // change the href of link.theme to match the rel of this
        $('.theme').attr('href',$(this).attr('rel'));
        // set a cookie to remember
        $.cookie('theme-cookie', $(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/', domain: '.nitrografixx.com'});
        // prevent this from reloading the browser
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Ok , i tried thtat as well and didn't work. removing all the optional options.

Comment: @MShack There are a lot of errors in your console because of Spry. May be that causes your other JS functions to fail!

Comment: i removed all the html , still doesn't set the cookie - http://www.nitrografixx.com/mflskin/test.html

Comment: @MShack Is it the same site?

Comment: i checked in FF , IE , Chrome , not working for me. It changes the stylesheets , but on page refresh the default.css loads , instead of alternative. The idea is if user selects alternative, that css loads on each visit, correct ?

Comment: @MShack Add the code which I have given in the answer at the end and give me a shout.

Comment: added , and when you click alternative , and refresh page , the css reverts itself back to default still

Comment: So this is not a cookie issue. There's some issue while loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82315/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-mshack).

Comment: Now it remembers only the "alternative" style on refresh , and won't load the default one ever

Comment: Actually, works perfectly fine for me... I am on Incognito Google Chrome 42!!! `:D`

Comment: ok , its working in Chrome and IE , but FF is not working , that is what i typically use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405336/jquery-cookie-plugin-not-working-for-firefox

Comment: Set path, but not the domain.

Comment: done  , correct ? but still a no go in FF , not stopped working in Chrome/IE as well , without the path set